# There are similar projects to Java libraries like Apache Commons?

Tags: java, apache-commons

I want to know if there are another projects to provide libraries for Java like the Apache Commons project. I got some useful things like Logging, ConnectionPool, Configurations, etc. from it, but maybe there is something that it won't cover.

At the moment, I don't need anything specific, but only want to know if there are similar projects. I want to know this because I can be wasting my time in things that are already done.

Comment: Avoid [Commons Logging](http://www.google.com/search?q=commons+logging+classloader+issues) if you can. The classloader heartburn is not worth it. And Commons DBCP has only been recently revived; BoneCP and c3p0 are better options.

Comment: Agreed - Commons Logging: Just Say No

Comment: Oh, I did a mistake (or not?), I'm using log4j. This is not Commons Logging, is?

Comment: Commons Logging is not log4j. Commons Logging is a logging facade rather than a logger; it can use log4j as it's logger.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's Google's [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)

Answer (score 1):

That's a pretty broad question.  The Commons libs cover a lot of territory, but if you are using a framework such as Spring, there are even more implementations of common functionality in the scope of the framework, especially in the Spring sub-projects.